# choosing between android and iOS for a programming novice

Tags: android, c++, python, ios

I've been wanting to get into mobile/tablet app development but I'm not sure whether to go with iOS or Android.  Here are a few specific questions I had:

1. What would you recommend for someone who has a background in python and C++?
2. Is developing for the honeycomb os for tablets pretty much the same as android development?
3. This might be a silly question but I've also wanted to start developing GUI programs for windows and Mac OS.  Is there any way to write something in python using PyQt or wxPython and make it usable on mobile operating systems as well?  Just wondering.

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Python, PyQt, wxPython, C++, Android, iOS or GUI Programs for Windows and Mac OS?

Comment: I vote for closing. This question has been asked for 10000000 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would you recommend for someone who has a background in python
>   and C++?

Android uses Java as the main programming language, iOS uses Objective-C.
IMHO Java is easier to learn and more consistent compared to Obj-C.

> Is developing for the honeycomb os for tablets pretty much the same as
>   android development?

Honeycomb is Android version 3. So yes, developing for Honeycomb is developing for Android, albeit differences in UI guidelines.

> This might be a silly question but I've also wanted to start
>   developing GUI programs for windows and Mac OS. Is there any way to
>   write something in python using PyQt or wxPython and make it usable on
>   mobile operating systems as well? Just wondering.

Mouse and keyboard interactions are pretty much different than touch screen interactions (assuming you're talking about touch screen smartphones). When I began mobile app development, I always use the wrong sizes for the buttons etc.

The nearest can be done is maybe using Adobe AIR that allows you to deploy to desktops and mobile phones using same code base.

Comment: -1. Jave is not easier to learn and certinaly not "consistent" than OC.

Comment: It depends on the perspective, but Java should be easier to learn. The GUI development is another thing...

Comment: Java and C++ have very similar syntax. So java should be easier to learn in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> What would you recommend for someone who has a background in python and C++?

I would recommend going for android development. As Android is an open source OS, in future more devices will have it installed for its cost effectiveness. Android development needs you to learn java, which unlike objective-C, will not restrict your development capability to one brand of OS. Also java and C++ are very similar syntactically, hence will be easier for you to learn it. Java is everywhere. So go with Android.

> Is developing for the honeycomb os for tablets pretty much the same as android development?

Yes, its the same. There are a few new features in honeycomb dedicated to tablets, but creating some samples on honeycomb should get you started for both.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, your current skill set is insufficient for neither Android nor iOS. So, it doesn't matter which platform you decide. Either way, you will have some deep learning curve. However, you could write code in C++ for Android and iOS.

I'm not aware that Python supports both iOS and Android. There're a dozen of framework for that, like Flash. If you're not confident in Flash, you might as well develop GUIs for each indidivual platform. Remember, Android and iOS and PCs have very different UI design, any general framework for building an app for all platforms could be very limitied.

Comment: writing C++ code for Android is out of the scope of the question- it requires a knowledge of the Native Development Kit and is not useful for anything besides games and heavy computation.  This question is more about general app development, which C++ cannot be used for on Android.